# Установка Apache+PHP+MySQL на ХР

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Пытаюсь поставить Apache+PHP+MySQL на ХР. 
Пробовала по этим ссылкам делать:
http://webadequate.ru/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-web-servera/10-podklyuchenie-php-k-apache.html
http://siteis.ru/rabota-s-serverom/ustanovka-servera-apache
Проблема возникает на этапе после создания и изменения php.ini
По адресу localhost/phpinfo.php должна открываться таблица с параметрами, а у меня только 404 The requested URL /phpinfo.php was not found on this server.
Пробовала и проверяла все не один раз по разным примерам. 
Подскажите, в чем проблема.

Comment: Вы целенаправленно хотите поставить всё по отдельности? Может быть готовый WAMP сэкономил вам кучу времени? Например, OpenServer?

Comment: В httpd.conf найдите строку DocumentRoot и проверьте верно ли указан путь.

Answer (score 1):

Проще использовать уже готовые сборки, я, например, раньше пользовался EASYPHP.    
На хабре есть статья с различными сборками и кратким описанием, можно почитать тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144242/    
Что же касается вашей ошибки, то не могу подсказать )

ps: [[@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh), как вам удается писать коменты под вопросом? ) никак не найду кнопочку.

Comment: @Stuf - Ваши [привилегии][1] на проекте. Чем выше уважение, тем больше возможностей.

> комментирование повсеместно - требуется репутация 50


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/privileges/

Comment: @Stuf - ну вот, теперь и вы можете писать комментарии =) 

Comment: @ua6xh да, спасибо ))